# "ConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row" thrown with @OneToMany relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

I have a OneToMany relationship as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Curriculum {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<WorkExperience> workExperiences;
        ...
```

Here is the WorkExperience entity:

```
@Entity
public class WorkExperience {
...
```

When I try to delete a WorkExperience as follows:

```
@Override
public void deleteWorkExperience(long workExperienceId) {
  workExperienceRepository.delete(workExperienceId);
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
 org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bignibou`.`curriculum_work_experiences`, CONSTRAINT `FKFA6D4B9F8B68AA0C` FOREIGN KEY (`work_experiences`) REFERENCES `work_experience` (`id`))
```

My questions are as follows:

1. If I want to keep the join table i.e. `curriculum_work_experiences`, how can I properly delete a WorkExperience?
2. I noticed that by manually setting the fk to `on cascade delete` in MySql, it worked properly but I am not sure what is the JPA annotation necessary to achieve what I did manually...

Comment: Check similar question has been answered here:
[Cannot delete or update a parent row ConstraintViolationException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641181/cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-constraintviolationexception/40645955#40645955)

Answer (score -1):

Orphan Removal is the way to go in this scenario. You cant delete it directly by using workExperienceId cause its a uni directional join table relationship and the database is constrained with a foreign key referential integrity  , you will have to delete it by using the Curriculum entity , you need to get a reference to Set workExperiences and remove it from that set but first make sure to add the orpanRemoval=true element to the @OneToMany annotation as shown below, this attribute forces any references in the join table to be deleted as well.

```
@Entity
public class Curriculum {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<WorkExperience> workExperiences;
        ...
```

Comment: I tried as you advised. It actually does not work... Please not that it is supposed to delete a line in both the `work_experience` and the `curriculum_work_experiences` tables.